# Using firebase cloud messaging for user to user push notifications

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

How can one use firebase cloud messaging to enable any specific user of your android app send push notifications to another specific user

Comment: which framework?

Comment: It's an android application

Comment: There are hundreds of tutorials for this already, so I recommend checking out some of those: https://www.google.com/search?q=Using+firebase+cloud+messaging+for+user+to+user+push+notifications